# Spark Save DStream to HDFS

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Having issues writing from a DataFrame to HDFS in yarn-client mode. On spark-submit a directory called `System.currentTimeMillis()` is created under the hdfs path, but is empty.

Streaming is supposed to occur for certain duration of time, after which it stops.

Application works fine on my local (but dstream is written to a local file)

Code in use is below:

```
 val tweetSchemaString = "tweetID tweetCreatedAt tweetUserName tweetUserScreenName tweetUserLocation"

    import org.apache.spark.sql.{Row, SparkSession}
    import org.apache.spark.sql._
    import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
    import org.apache.spark.sql.types.{StructType,StructField,StringType}

    val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master(args(1)).getOrCreate
    //val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate

    val schema = StructType(tweetSchemaString.split(" ").map(fieldName => StructField(fieldName,StringType,true)))

    tweets.foreachRDD(
      tweet => {
        if(!tweet.partitions.isEmpty){
          val rowRDD = tweet.map(
            rddTweet => Row(
              rddTweet.getId().toString(),
              rddTweet.getCreatedAt.toString(),
              rddTweet.getUser().getName,
              rddTweet.getUser().getScreenName,
              rddTweet.getUser.getLocation
             )
          )
          //Get the Singleton Instance of SQL Context
          val sqlContext = SQLContext.getOrCreate(tweet.sparkContext)
          val tweetsDF = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD,schema)
          tweetsDF.createOrReplaceTempView("tweetsTable")
          println("=======================================================")
          println("===================WRITING TO HDFS=====================")

          tweetsDF.write.json("hdfs://url:8020/home/gib/"+ System.currentTimeMillis())
        }
      }
    )
    // Start Streaming Context
    ssc.start()
    //ssc.awaitTermination()
    ssc.awaitTerminationOrTimeout(60000 * streamFor)
    ssc.stop()
```

on execution
`spark-submit --executor-memory 1g --driver-memory 1g  --class str.Streamer TwitterStreamV1-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar 2 yarn-client`

Error below pops up the specified duration of execution time, in this case **2** mins

This occurs after a signal is sent to stop receivers

```
18/04/16 11:11:31 INFO ReceiverTracker: Sent stop signal to all 1 receivers
18/04/16 11:11:31 ERROR ReceiverTracker: Deregistered receiver for stream 0: Stopped by driver
```

**ERROR**

```
18/04/16 11:11:34 ERROR InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand: Aborting job.
java.lang.InterruptedException
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:623)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1873)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1886)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1906)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:525)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.json(DataFrameWriter.scala:467)
        at dsti.Streamer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Streamer.scala:100)
        at dsti.Streamer$$anonfun$main$1.apply(Streamer.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
        at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:247)
        at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:246)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$
```

Is there a way i can achieve this?

1. Stream and write to a file
2. Stop Streaming and Writing after a certain specified time?